# ¿Como ajustar una imagen que ocupe todo el contenedor de un card bootstrap?

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente problema y no logro solucionarlo o al menos creo que ya me confundí porque pensé que ya lo tenia, ya que si visualizo imágenes de la misma altura no hay problemas, pero si hay imágenes con un tamaño mas largo se sale del contenedor div.

Un ejemplo aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar algunas imagenes con una altura mas grande se sale de contenedor. Como solucionara esto para que todos se vieran del mismo tamaño?

Mi código para visualizar las imágenes:

```
<div class="card" >
        <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Evidencias</h5>
              <hr>
             <div class="row" >
                @foreach ($evidencias as $evidencia)
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-2" style="height:100px; margin-bottom: 10px;" >
                           <div  class="card" style=" height:100%;">
                             @if($evidencia->url)
                             <a href="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}" class="card-img-top" style="height:100%;">
                             </a>

                             @endif
                           </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
             </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Intentaste con la clase h-100? En vez de el style.

Answer (score 1):

el div de con las clases col-12 col-md-2 no debe tener definido el tamaño para que se acomode al tamaño de los elemento que se encuentran dentro, al que se le deberá definir un tamaño es al div que se encuentra dentro.

ejemplo:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-2" style="" >
                           <div  class="card" style="height:100px;">
                             @if($evidencia->url)
                             <a href="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="{{ url($evidencia->url) }}" class="card-img-top" style="height:100%;">
                             </a>

                             @endif
                           </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: si quito eso el div se ajusta la imagen mas largo y eso las otras  se les ve un borde blanco por debajo

Comment: intendta definir un tamaño definido solo a la etiqueta <img style=""height:100px;width:100px"">